# Encode ASCII Files

Tags: delphi

this question will have a very simple answers which is **yes** or **no** I guess ?

If I encode from x64 bit unicode delphi app my stringlist like this

```
StringList.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.ASCII);
```

is there any other limitation , difference in file layout while writing this file with the statement

```
StringList.SaveToFile(FileName);
```

or

```
StringList.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

I'm afraid on line length and control char issues between both versions....Answer NO will make me happy.

Comment: If that parameter had no effect on the output, why do you think it would exist at all?

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 and the Windows 'Ansi' codepages are all superset of ASCII. As such, if the string list only contains characters in the ASCII range, the three statements you listed will be equivalent if you prepend the last with this:

```
StringList.WriteBOM := False;
```

This is because by default, `TStrings` will write out a small marker (a BOM) to denote UTF-8 text.

Comment: The first and third statements would be equivalent, but not necessarily the second. Its output will differ if the encoding is UTF-16.

Comment: @RobKennedy - the single-parameter version of `SaveToFile` will use `TEncoding.Default` unless `LoadFromFile` or `LoadFromStream` had previously been called and a BOM was found, or the `DefaultEncoding` property has been explicitly set beforehand - and `TEncoding.Default` maps to `TEncoding.Ansi` on Windows and `TEncoding.UTF8` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the extra details to reinforce my comment, @Chris.

Comment: @RobKennedy - well if that's what you actually meant, great ('if the encoding is UTF-16' is ambiguous - `TStringList` will always hold UTF-16 data given that is the encoding of the `string` type, but that says nothing about what the `SaveToFile` method does)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is simply in the encoding used. This in turn, of course, leads to differences in size. So ASCII files will be smaller than UTF-16 (what you get with `TEncoding.Unicode`. And UTF-8 files could be the same size as ASCII, or larger than UTF-16.

I guess you are asking if using ASCII or UTF-8 in any way damages the text that is written. Well, using ASCII will if the text contains non-ASCII characters. ASCII can only encode 127 characters.

On the other hand, UTF-8 is a full encoding of Unicode. Which means that

```
StringList.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
StringList.LoadFromFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8);
```

results in the list having exactly the same content as it did before the save.

You ask if lines can be truncated by `SaveToFile`. They cannot.

Another point to make is that 32/64 bit is not relevant here. The code behaves in exactly the same way under 32 and 64 bit. The issues are always to do with encoding.

I would also note that the title of your question is somewhat mis-leading. When you encode with `TEncoding.UTF8` you not do not have an ASCII file.

Comment: You're last statement isn't true *if* a BOM isn't written out *and* there were only characters in the ASCII range

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Not the way I think of it. I would say that was still a UTF-8 file. It's just that it is indistinguishable from an ASCII file.

Comment: I would say it is both. ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 (or UTF-8 is a superset). Which means that mathemetically speaking a string containing only ASCII characters will be both ASCII and UTF-8 (and ISO-8859-1...). 1 is also a natural number and an integral number and a fractional number etc. You cannot distinquish.

Comment: @RitsaertHornstra I think about it like this. If you wrote `StringList.SaveToFile(FileName, TEncoding.UTF8)` and then wrote `StringList.LoadFromFile(FileName, ...)` what would you write in the `...`. I'm pretty sure that you would not write `TEncoding.ASCII`. If you knew the file contained only ASCII characters, then you would save and load using `TEncoding.ASCII`. If you wanted to support the full range of Unicode then you would use a Unicode encoding like `TEncoding.UTF8`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I see no benefit in that given the concrete behaviour of the TEncoding API on invalid input (as at XE5), which is to never raise an exception and instead return either nothing or something. E.g., compare the behaviour of `TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('é')`, `TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('œ')`, and `TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes('ʧ')`.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston I do not understand that comment. You see no benefit in what?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no benefit of ever using `TEncoding.ASCII`. In response to my point that an ASCII file is in fact a valid UTF-8 file, you seemed to say that it's the intention of the programmer that counts - but if so, `TEncoding` is a false friend because it doesn't communicate failures consistently.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Let's try it this way. Suppose you have a file that was saved using UTF-8, but happens to contain only ASCII characters. How would you load it? Would you check first for characters >= 128 and if found use `TEncoding.UTF8`, or otherwise use `TEncoding.ASCII`? I know I would not. I would use `TEncoding.UTF8` always. Another way to think about it is that the encoding is a property of the file rather than its contents.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - TEncoding.UTF8 of course. It was *you* who wrote 'If you knew the file contained only ASCII characters, then you would save and load using TEncoding.ASCII'.